# elastic search - Kibana - Jenkins Pipeline job log

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, kibana

How to configure jenkins pipeline job log into kibana. Followed the steps mentioned in this url: http://www.admintome.com/blog/logging-jenkins-jobs-using-elasticsearch-and-kibana/ . configured basic jenkins job with elastic serach . But pipeline job, I couldn't find the option "Send console log to Logstash".

Answer (score 0):

Which type of project did you create ?

> I only see this option available for Freestyle type Jenkins Jobs. For
>   pipeline type jobs you will need to code this in Groovy

Comment: yes .. you are right.. for freestyle , it is working . i could see the log in Elastic search. how can i do the same for pipeline job? is it possible to enable at global level instead of configuring each job?